# Gnarly equality proof? Or not?

Tags: proof-verification, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have this gnarly equality which Mathematica's `Reduce` says it doesn't have the chops to handle:
$\left.k\in \mathbb{Z}\land \left\lceil \frac{k-2}{2}\right\rceil  \left(\left\lceil \frac{k-2}{2}\right\rceil -((k-2) \bmod 2)+2\right)+k+1=\left\lceil \frac{k}{2}\right\rceil  \left(\left\lceil \frac{k}{2}\right\rceil -(k \bmod 2)+2\right)\right]$,
so I simplified to this: 
$k\in \mathbb{Z}\land (k \bmod 2)+k=2 \left\lceil \frac{k}{2}\right\rceil$, which Mathematica reduces to: $c_1\in \mathbb{Z}\land k=c_1$.

So, can I say that this proves the equality for $k\geq1$? Or is something subtle going on? Do I need to do more?

Comment: What a totally rad equation dude!

Comment: way to rad for mathematica you need a gnarly turing oracle to be safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rad, dude. You are correct on all counts. The equality is too gnarly for Mathematica; your reduction is correct; and your interpretation of Mathematica's final answer is good. Way to go.

You can actually go further: Mathematica's answer is good for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, not just $k \in \mathbb{Z}^{\geq 1}$.

Comment: New equality: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1801922/28555

Answer (score 3):

Good job simplifying the equality. Let me just show how to finish it off by hand, without Mathematica's help.

The mod operation can conveniently be *defined* in terms of the floor function by

$$x \bmod y = x - y \lfloor x/y \rfloor,\quad \text{for all real }x \text{ and real }y \ne 0.$$

Try to understand why this is the right definition. We are subtracting a multiple of $y$ from $x$. Test it out with a few small integers to see what happens. By the way, for the sake of completeness note also that we define $x \bmod 0 = x$ for all $x.$

Substituting the definition of mod into your equation yields

$$k - 2 \lfloor k/2 \rfloor + k = 2\lceil k/2 \rceil,$$

and rearranging we get

$$k = \lfloor k/2 \rfloor + \lceil k/2 \rceil.$$

Rad! This last equation holds for all integer $k$. If you'd like to verify it, check the odd and even cases separately (ie. write $k = 2j$ and $k = 2j + 1$.)

Comment: +1, I will use it. And I will cite both answers. Thanks.

Comment: New equality: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1801922/28555